How to recreate the iPython console from Pycharm in VScode
So I'm moving from pycharm to VScode, because a lot of people I work with use jupyter notebooks, and im not going to pay for pycharm professional. For my old workflow, I used to use the IPython console from pycharm.
So I would have Ipython as my default interpreter, and every script i was working on, I would change to run in console (which was running in Ipython by default). I could also automatically run scripts everytime i started a new console, and the console had an extremely handy variable view, where I could see exactly which variables were defined, and their shape and stuff. So while coding, I would run each new line in the console first to see if it worked before adding it to the script.
Does anyone else work like this? And has anyone else recreated this in VScode? Honestly just an implementation of the dynamic variable view would suffice for me, otherwise working with jupyter notebooks is quite similar to what I was doing.

Have you read https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks ?

VSCode documentation should include all details about how to visualize variables in Jupyter notebook.Would you share a specific issue if you are encountering one?
